# Gitlab ci issue with passing artifacts to Downstream pipeline with trigger and needs keywords

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-pipelines

I am working on a multi-pipeline project, and using `trigger` keyword to trigger a downstream pipeline, but I'm not able to pass artifacts created in the upstream project. I am using `needs` to get the artifact like so:

Downstream Pipeline block to get artifacts:

```
needs:
    - project: workspace/build
        job: build
        ref: master
        artifacts: true
```

Upstream Pipeline block to trigger:

```
build:
    stage: build
    artifacts:
    paths:
        - ./policies
    expire_in: 2h
    only:
    - master
    script:
    - echo 'Test'
    allow_failure: false

triggerUpstream:
    stage: deploy
    only:
    - master
    trigger:
    project: workspace/deploy
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts:
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you redacted the `strategy` part of the trigger? If so, the downstream pipeline is only able to fetch artifacts from *completed* pipelines. So if there isn't one it'll show this error

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a problem sharing artifacts between pipelines as well as between projects. It is known bug and has been reported here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/228586

You can find a workaround there but since it needs to add access token to project it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your upstream pipeline job "Build" is set to only store its artifacts for 2 hours (from the `expire_in: 2h` line. Your downstream pipeline must have run at least 2 hours later than the artifacts were created, so the artifact expired and was erased, generating that error.

To solve it you can either update the `expire_in` field to however long you need them to be active (so for example if you know the downstream pipeline will run up to 5 days later, set it to 5d for 5 days), or rerun the Build job to recreate the artifacts.

You can read more about the `expire_in` keyword and artifacts in general from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but have tried `expire_in: never` too, but still same issue. Also, in error its not showing which artifact it is missing, so just wondering if I am missing anything in `needs` step.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a problem with expired artifacts, the error is incorrect.  In my case I am able to download the artifacts as a zip directly from the UI on the executed job.  My `expire_in` is set to `1 week` yet I am still getting this message.